# AndroidX and Android Jetpack

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack

As per my knowledge Androidx is itself a library, and android jetpack is a set of libraries. Is Androidx a library in Android Jetpack? I am a little bit confused about Androidx vs Android Jetpack. Can anyone explain it to me clearly?

Comment: `androidx` is a namespace that differentiates "support libraries" from code shipped as part of the android platform. Android Jetpack is just another name for these `androidx`-namespaced libraries, and is focused on supporting google's recommended solutions for common android tasks.

Comment: Each of the Jetpack libraries is located in a package that starts with androidx. For this reason, you will sometimes hear the terms “AndroidX” and “Jetpack” used as synonyms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [AndroidX FAQ doc](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:docs/faq.md):

> **How are `androidx` and AndroidX related to Jetpack?**
>
> They are all the same thing! In a sentence, `androidx` is the packaging and AndroidX is the development workflow for all components in Jetpack. Jetpack is the external branding for libraries within `androidx`.
>
> In more detail, Jetpack is the external branding for the set of components, tools, and guidance that improve the developer experience on Android. AndroidX is the open-source development project that defines the workflow, versioning, and release policies for ALL libraries included in Jetpack. All libraries within the `androidx` Java package follow a consistent set of API design guidelines, conform to SemVer and alpha/beta revision cycles, and use the Android issue tracker for bugs and feature requests.

Comment: I've once opened a retagging request on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393964/similar-tags-android-jetpack-android-architecture-components-androidx), but it somehow didn't receive much attention.

Answer (score -1):

`androidx.*` has been replacing the old `android.support.*` and `android.arch.*` set of libraries.
It also includes support to all the older libraries (except for the deprecated one, of course).
Android Jetpack is a suite of tools developed by Google to write applications that follow certain standards as well as ease the job of developers like us.
Part of the Android Jetpack "universe" is Room (a library that facilitates the writing of an SQL database), DataStore (currently still in beta, but soon it will replace SharedPreference for the persistence of settings when for example we set Dark mode in the app, we close it, and we expect to still have Dark mode ON when we open it back), LiveData (for asynchronous data stream), ......and others.
All this goes hand in hand with the continuous development of the Kotlin language and the never-ending usefulness of COROUTINES, just to mention one.
I hope this overview was of use to the readers.